# can i give OnclickListener and onCreateContextmenu to a single Text view?

Tags: android

Thanks in Advance....
Can any one knows, I have  a requirement to perfrom  OnclickListener ans onCreateContextmenu to a single Text View. Is it possible if YES? then Can any one help me out from this.....

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it. but before that you have to register your textview for context menu after that you can open your context menu when click on textview.

Comment: Thanks...it works fine ...t there is a small issue I am using OnClick for for moving text up and dowm and registerforcontextmenu for showing menu list...Problem here is if I am using registerforcontextmenu for textview1 then onclick is not performing on the Textview1...Why I dont know....I need your suggestion ..thank you –

Answer (score 0):

Register `OnclickListener` for `onclick` and use `registerforcontextmenu` api for Context menu to be launched for your TextView

Comment: Thanks...it works fine ...t there is a small issue I am using OnClick for for moving text up and dowm and registerforcontextmenu for showing menu list...Problem here is if I am using registerforcontextmenu for textview1 then onclick is not performing on the Textview1...Why I dont know....I need your suggestion ..thank you